# Can' t execute svn update command after chekout with jenkins subversion plugin( svnkit)

Tags: svn, jenkins, command-prompt, jenkins-plugins, svnkit

OS : Windows 8

I have install a jenkins server with subversion plugin (SVNKit) version 2.4 of plugin.
I have made a checkout on a svn+ ssh server an all is work.
When i try to make an update command in manual cmd mode, nothing appears. There's no finish.

I use a sssh connexion. I think it was a problem with user profil but if i do a checkout in manual command line (without jenkins),  the update commands works well.

My svn version is 1.7.

Maybe it comes from a different way between SVNKit and svn but i find nothing to resolve it.

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

A local working copy of the SVN checkout has a certain format. Usually they are not backwards compatible.

> jenkins server with subversion plugin (SVNKit) version 2.4 of plugin

That information above is not enough. SVNKit version 2.4 supports many versions of working copy format.

Under **Manage Jenkins** > **Configure System**, find "Subversion" section, and look for value under "Subversion Workspace Version".

That version is the version of your working copy format, and when Jenkins does the SVN checkout, the folder will be in that version.

You have to make sure that your command line tool that you use is of the same version as that number in Jenkins. If you downgrade that number in Jenkins, you will have to blow away the existing checkout and do a fresh checkout

Comment: Thank you for your answer. We have made a verification and we are in the same version. The Subversion workspace version : 1.7.
When we activate client log, we have this message : initialised hmac-sha1 server- client mac algorithm‏